# Select comparando no where 2 colunas de diferentes tabelas

Tags: sql

Estou tentando montar uma consulta mas não está trazendo nada.

```
SELECT EMP, COD, VEV, SEQ, TIP, NUM, EMI, VEN, DTR, GRU, PRO, QTD, PVE, TOT, FAT, COM, COO, REF, VAR, hcli.NOM as "VENDEDOR",
hemp.enc from hcov 
    INNER JOIN hcli ON hcov.COD = hcli.COD
    JOIN hemp ON hemp.cod = hcov.emp 
WHERE (hcli.NOM NOT LIKE '%COOPERATIVA%')
AND (DTR >= date '2020-01-01')
AND (COD NOT IN (24545 ,10368 ,13149, 10448, 11041, 30610, 6834) )
AND (GRU <> 266 OR GRU <> 269 OR GRU <> 272)
AND ( (VEV <> 37125) AND (COO NOT IN (987209, 23631, 927500, 22763, 38736 ) ) )
AND (num = 84831 and emp = 24)
AND (hemp.enc <> hcov.cod)
```

O Problema esta na última linha da consulta, pois quando eu tiro ela funciona.. porém eu preciso dela pra comparação. Por acaso estou montando de forma errada?

Abaixo uma imagem do resultado sem a última linha da query >
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qualquer comparação com "null" retorna como "false" uma solução é algo do tipo AND ((hemp.enc <> hcov.cod) or (hcov.cod is null)) mas precisa definir bem o que fazer nestes casos , informe o SGBD pois o tratamento de nulo (nvl COALESCE isnull)

Comment: mas como eu faria então pra fazer esta comparação e trazer na query somente se COD for diferente de ENC ??

Comment: coloquei desta forma que vc falou deu certo... AND ((hemp.enc <> hcov.cod) or (hemp.enc is null))